# fetch only available products in a date range

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table like one is orders and other one is product. product type is rental so the items are sent for rent and then return. now , I want that when user search a date range let say 13 june 2017 to 21 june 2017 then only those product should appear who dont have any entry in ordersell in between these date ranges.
like a product a should not appear if its booked for 14 june to 17 or 21 june to 23 or 11 june to 15 june. All i want that the range selected should not colide with ant order date. Table order have fields(just needed fields mentioning here)
order table

```
id product_id from_date   to_date
1   12        2017/04/12  2017/04/21
2   12       2017/05/2    2017/05/8
3   32       2016/12/1    2016/12/7
```

product table

```
id name etc etc
12 p1   23   12
32 p23  22  32
```

I am using mysql and php
in mysql query(cannot show you the full query for some reason)
there is join bw product and orders table and this where condition in the query

```
WHERE "2017-04-13"NOT BETWEEN `orders`.`from_date` AND `orders`.`to_date` AND "2017-04-21"NOT BETWEEN `orders`.`from_date` AND `orders`.`to_date`
```

As I said that there is a join between those tables .there are also some other older orders in order table, so the join is actually creating the problem. try to understand "1 - join happens::: all rows from order table where product_id matches are fetched " then "2- where condition happens our rows falling in between these ranges are eliminated but those ranges who dont fall in this range are not filtered then we still have that product"

Comment: Can you share what you've tried?

Comment: this can be achieved in mysql or in php alone very easy did you do some research and what did you try post your code and we can find the errors otherwise start by trying and writing some code.

Comment: @Gert I included a part ofmy query in my question

Comment: @JayBlanchard I updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a NOT EXISTS statement:

```
select *
from products p
where not exists (
    select *
    from orders o
    where o.product_id = p.id
      and to_date   >= '2017-06-13'
      and from_date <= '2017-06-21'
)
```

I words: Select all products that have no orders with an overlaping date range.

Comment: Let me try this

Answer (score 0):

Replace static dates with your php variables that contains user input for search.

```
SELECT *
FROM product p INNER JOIN orders o
ON p.id=o.product_id
WHERE (from_date NOT BETWEEN '2017-06-13' AND '2017-06-21')
AND (to_date NOT BETWEEN '2017-06-13' AND '2017-06-21')
AND p.id=$pid;
```

Comment: I am already doing that this is just to show you how I am doing

Comment: then what is the problem?

Comment: Add one more condition, check it I just edited the query.

Comment: there are also some other older orders in order table, so the join is actually creating the problem. try to understand "1 - join happens::: all rows from order table where product_id matches are fetched " then "2- where condition happens our rows falling in between these ranges are eliminated but those ranges who dont fall in this range are not filtered then we still have that product"